# I am unable to update record in mysql using java/jsp

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am unable to update a specific record in my database. I am unable to find the error and Eclipse doesn't show any error.

Here is my bean class

```
public class Category {
    
    private int id;
    private String category_type;
    private String description;
    private String active_flag;
    
    public Category() {
        super();
    }

    public Category(int id, String category_type, String description, String active_flag) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.category_type = category_type;
        this.description = description;
        this.active_flag = active_flag;
    }

    public Category(String category_type, String description, String active_flag) {
        super();
        this.category_type = category_type;
        this.description = description;
        this.active_flag = active_flag;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCategory_type() {
        return category_type;
    }

    public void setCategory_type(String category_type) {
        this.category_type = category_type;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getActive_flag() {
        return active_flag;
    }

    public void setActive_flag(String active_flag) {
        this.active_flag = active_flag;
    }
    
}
```

Here is my DAO class

```
package com.estore.dao;
public class CategoryDao {
    
    private static Connection connection;
    
    public CategoryDao() {}  //constructor
    
    public static int addCategory(Category category) throws SQLException
    {
        connection = db.getConnection();
        int status=0;  
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement("insert into prodcat(category_type, description, active_flag) values (?, ?, ?)");
            pstm.setString(1, category.getCategory_type());
            pstm.setString(2, category.getDescription());
            pstm.setString(3, category.getActive_flag());
            status = pstm.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;  
    
    }
    
    public static int updateCategory(Category category) throws SQLException
    {
        connection = db.getConnection();
        int status = 0;
        try
        {
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);
            
            PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE prodcat set category_type = ?, description = ?, active_flag = ? where id = ?");
            pstm.setString(1, category.getCategory_type());
            pstm.setString(2,  category.getDescription());
            pstm.setString(3,  category.getActive_flag());
            pstm.setInt(4,  category.getId());
            status = pstm.executeUpdate();
            
            
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;  
    }

    public static int deleteCategory(Category category) throws SQLException
    {
        connection = db.getConnection();
        int status = 0;
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement pstm = connection.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM prodcat where id = ?");
            pstm.setInt(1, category.getId());
            status = pstm.executeUpdate();
            
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return status;
    }

    public  static List<Category> getAllCategory() throws SQLException
    {
        connection = db.getConnection();
        List <Category> category = new ArrayList<>();
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM prodcat"); 
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                int id = rs.getInt("id");
                String category_type = rs.getString("category_type");
                String description = rs.getString("description");
                String active_flag = rs.getString("active_flag");
                category.add(new Category(id, category_type, description, active_flag));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return category;
    }

    public static Category getCategoryById(int id) throws SQLException
    {
        connection = db.getConnection();
        
        Category category = new Category();
        try
        {
            PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStatement("select * from prodCat where id = ?"); 
            ps.setInt(1, id);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                category.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                category.setCategory_type(rs.getString("category_type"));
                category.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
                category.setActive_flag(rs.getString("active_flag"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return category;
    }
 }
```

All the records are displayed using viewcategory.jsp class as shown below. When I click edit category the editCategoryform.jsp is called and It is working fine. But when I edit the record and press button it will not update recod. but delete record and insert record method working fine.

```
<table>
             <thead>
                 <tr>
                     <th>#</th>
                     <th>Category Type</th>
                     <th>Description</th>
                     <th>Active</th>
                     <th>Edit Tab</th>
                     <th>Delete Tab</th>
                 </tr>
                 <% List<Category> listCategory = CategoryDao.getAllCategory();
                    request.setAttribute("listCategory", listCategory);
                 %>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                <c:forEach var="category" items="${listCategory}">
              <tr>

                 <td><c:out value="${category.getId()}" /></td>
                 <td><c:out value="${category.getCategory_type()}" /></td>
                 <td><c:out value="${category.getDescription()}" /></td>
                 <td><c:out value="${category.getActive_flag()}" /></td>
                 <td><a href="editCategoryform.jsp?id=${category.getId()}">Edit Category</a></td>
                 <td><a href="deleteCategory.jsp?id=${category.getId()}">Delete Category</a></td>
              </tr>
                </c:forEach>
               
            </tbody>
       </table>
```

My editCategoryForm.jsp class has similar code like shown below and it is working fine and this  file calling editCategory.jsp file to update record

```
<input type="text" name="description" value="<%= cat.getDescription()%>
```

My editCategory.jsp code is shown below here I am calling dao class's method "updateCategory"
but is not working

```
<%
     int i = CategoryDao.updateCategory(cat);
     if (i > 0)
       {
           response.sendRedirect("categoryMaster.jsp");
       } 
     else
       {
           response.sendRedirect("../error.jsp");
       }
%>
```

Comment: `connection.setAutoCommit(false);` - why?  You do not have this for `add` or `delete`

Comment: You did not show the interesting part: the form with the id and category description, and the handling of its sent form post. You can use developer mode in the browser (F12 or such) and check the (form) data sent and received. Further `${category.id}` will invoke `getId()` too.

Comment: thanks Joop, what i was missing was this line in editCategoryform :<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= cat.getId() %>" after adding this problem is solved